# PHP Short form (one line) to add a child array with key, if the child array is not empty

Tags: php

I've created some functions to create a tree structure and in this case I am using a part of the following snippet to add a child array, if at least one child exists.

```
    <?php

    function addArrayIfNotEmpty($entire_array, $key, $childArray){

    /*
    ### BEGIN: Possible as one line? ###
    */
    if (count($childArray) > 0) {
        $entire_array[$key] = $childArray;      
    }
    /*
    ### END: Possible as one line? ###
    */

    return $entire_array;
}


$my_array = array();

$first_array = array("orange", "banana");
$second_array = array();

$my_array = addArrayIfNotEmpty($my_array, "first", $first_array);
$my_array = addArrayIfNotEmpty($my_array, "second", $second_array);

var_dump($my_array);
```

In my real code, I only use the if condition between the comments with "BEGIN" and "END", but I would like to change this if condition to one line.

I tought about something like this:

```
$entire_array[$key] = count($childArray) > 0 ? $childArray : null;
```

But in this case, I will get an empty (unnecessary) child array.

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use a ternary operator as a statement and put the assignment in the `true` part:

```
function addArrayIfNotEmpty($entire_array, $key, $childArray){
    count($childArray) ? $entire_array[$key] = $childArray : null;
    return $entire_array;
}
```

but your existing `if` statement is a lot more readable.

Test code:

```
$entire_array = array();
$entire_array = addArrayIfNotEmpty($entire_array, 'key1', array());
print_r($entire_array);
$entire_array = addArrayIfNotEmpty($entire_array, 'key2', array('hello'));
print_r($entire_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [key2] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
        )

)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/0cHlA)